# Make For loop a Function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, indexing

I have created a code that checks the existence of an specific string inside array-object:

```
array = [{'grade': 'two'}, {'grade': 'three'}, {'grade': 'four'}];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {  
    if (array[i].grade === 'four'){      
        remIndex = [i]; 
        break;     
    }  
}

console.log(remIndex);
```

This code works.

But when i tried to convert it into a function it won't work:

```
function getARRAYINDEX( array, callOBJ, findSTRING){

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].callOBJ === findSTRING){
        remIndex = [i]; 
        break;
    }    
  }

  return remIndex;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the key name in a variable, you need to use the `[]` notation to access the property in the object. Replace this:

```
if (array[i].callOBJ === findSTRING){
```

with this:

```
if (array[i][callOBJ] === findSTRING){
```

Please do read this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) to know more about working with objects.

Answer (score 0):

When the property name is dynamic, you have to use [].

```
array[i][callOBJ]
```

and not

```
array[i].callOBJ
```

In the line above, callOBJ won't be evaluated and the code will try to get the property `callOBJ` and not the name stored in `callOBJ`.

```js
const array = [{'grade': 'two'}, {'grade': 'three'}, {'grade': 'four'}];


function getARRAYINDEX( array, callOBJ, findSTRING){
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i][callOBJ] === findSTRING){
        remIndex = [i];
        break;
    }
  }
  return remIndex;
}

console.log(getARRAYINDEX(array, 'grade', 'three'));
```

**By the way, you can achieve the same thing with `findIndex` ;)**

```js
const array = [{'grade': 'two'}, {'grade': 'three'}, {'grade': 'four'}];


function getARRAYINDEX( array, callOBJ, findSTRING){
  return [array.findIndex(item => item[callOBJ] === findSTRING)];
}

console.log(getARRAYINDEX(array, 'grade', 'three'));
```

Comment: i'm kind used to use like this way array[i].grade  etc...i seldom use the bracket version when calling object prop.. anyways thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

You need to define remIndex, if it doesn't come in the if block remIndex will be undefined and on return statement it will throw an exception. You can do it like this:

```
function getARRAYINDEX( array, callOBJ, findSTRING){
var remIndex;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

    if (array[i][callOBJ] === findSTRING){

        remIndex = [i]; 
        break;

    }

  }
  return remIndex;
}
```